# How to add more than one conditional in a javascript if statement

Tags: html, css

I have built a website, and it works fine when viewed on a computer in all browsers. But when I try to view it on my phone, it looks terrible. The header is normal size on the top, but all the page text is aligned on the far left of the screen, with a new line every three words. The structure of my website is that I have a div in the middle with all the content, with a 300px margin on each side. Why would this happen? How do I fix it?

Comment: The title of this question doesn't make much sense... anyways, you're looking for CSS media queries to control the page layout for different screen widths.

Comment: [Responsive design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) based on media queries ( modifying your CSS ) as @tymeJV told you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What you are referring to is termed as a Responsive Design.**

[What is Responsive Web Design?](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)
Responsive web design is to create web sites that look good on all devices.
Responsive web design is not a program or a JavaScript. Responsive web design is a must for mobile devices.

[image: Responsive Design]

Quoting from a [tutorial](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps), here are 3 easy steps for responsive design:

**Step 1. Meta Tag**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

**Step 2. HTML Structure**

[image: HTML Structure]

**Step 3. Media Queries**

[image: Media Queries 1]

Here's a [Demo](http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/responsive-design/index.html), and here the [source of the demo](http://view-source:http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/responsive-design/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

seems to me that you have a responsive design issue.. Look up media Queries. Add them to your site and configure your elements. Try working more with % and em.

Answer (score 0):

An often used framework to create responsive websites is [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).